# Battery drain issue on idle phone, how to find out the culprit?

Tags: battery, xiaomi, redmi

Overnight, starting from a 100% charge, all apps closed, even from a fresh reboot, screen of course off, my phone (Redmi 6) ends up with a ~90% charge. I know this is abnormal, as my previous phone (Redmi 5A, with worn out battery) ends up with ~99% in the same situation.

That's quite annoying to know that *something* needlessly drains my battery! I'm pretty sure it's due to some software bug. Encountering the issue as well on MIUI 10 and 11.

I'd like to find out the culprit in order to fix the issue. What can I do?

For the record, my syslog receives the following two errors *a lot* (several per second):

```
BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.qualcomm.qti.Performance
BoostFramework() Ux Perf : Exception = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.qualcomm.qti.UxPerformance
```

(then, just in case, I went to the Developer options and fully disabled logging, who knows! But it didn't fix the battery issue.)

Also for the record, I have already done a lot of googling about that battery drain issue, and tried the following fix: Go to "Settings > App > Permissions > Autostart" and disable everything (in my case I only had "Camera" enabled). Sadly, it didn't fix the issue.

**Update:**

I've had run "Battery usage stats" during the day, and it reported me that the screen was most (like 90~95%, as I recall) using the battery, followed by a few % by the networks (cell, wifi).

But here I just looked at "Battery usage stats" and it gave me interesting results: Screen 35%, Cell standby 31%, Wifi 24%…

This is something I was also suspecting. It's highly possible the battery drain is caused by network (both cell and wifi) activity, which in turn could be caused by some software bug. Even though I made sure that no apps or widgets are running. What could I do to investigate further this path? Maybe there is some setting (possibly advanced) that could fix the issue?

**Update 2:**

As suggested in the comments, I tried "airplane mode" (i.e. cell and wifi networks disabled) and it seems to solve the issue. I think that both, cell and wifi, cause battery drain.

However, that adds an annoying handling step, and I cannot receive calls while in airplane mode. I wish I could avoid that extra handling. I usually don't use wifi, so I'll try disabling only wifi and see if it's sufficient.

The MediaTek chipset of the Redmi 6 definitely seems to be a bad pick. This chipset forbids almost any custom ROM, and now I discover it's not energy-efficient at all for networks…

**Update 3:**

Some feedback after an extensive period of testing. I can keep cell network and mobile data always on, turning the wifi off seems to be sufficient. Overnight, the battery goes down to barely 99%, it reaches 98% at the very worst… sometimes it even stays at 100% :)

Coupled with a good mobile plan, I just keep the wifi always off, and no longer think about this issue :)

Comment: 1. What do you see in battery usage? 2. Is the phone hot/warm on morning, or cold? If hot, it is likely power consumption issue. If cold, it is more likely power supply issue.

Comment: @v6ak 1) I have added an update to my question. Thanks to you, I looked again at "Battery usage stats" and it gave me some hint. 2) Phone is cold (and just to make sure: it is unplugged). I think the battery is drained slow enough so that the phone doesn't warm up.

Comment: What happens when you put the phone in flight mode for a night?

Comment: Is your phone in air plane mode (Wifi and mobile disabled)? Because I have never seen a device that has a battery usage of 1% overnight without having all interfaces disabled.

Comment: @GrasDouble Aha, for some reason, I implicitly assumed it was being charged overnight. If not, then the phone is unlikely to be hot on morning.

Comment: I'll try the "airplane mode" over a night, and I'm pretty confident it will fix the issue. However, it would be annoying having to switch the airplane mode on/off again and again… and I wouldn't receive calls/messages… I'd prefer to avoid having to do this… Is this some design flaw of the Mediatek Helio P22 chipset?

Comment: I added "update 2" to my question. Any suggestion to improve the situation would be very welcome :)

Comment: I also noticed this now, my wifi usage shows as it is "active" all the time in the battery usage graph details.  I wonder if it's got to do with changing the wifi hardware but keeping the same SSID and password? That's the only thing I've done recently that might have started causing this? Perhaps "forget the wifi network" on the phone and re enter the password by connecting again to it?

Comment: Another question, is your Wifi-Assistant off? Goto to Settings -> Wifi -> Additional Settings to turn it off

Comment: Related: [WiFi drains battery even if it's off](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127176/wifi-drains-battery-even-if-its-off)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, it seems to be related to media control apps like Spotify and Google Home mini always staying on and keeping wifi awake.
Also check for any other network connected devices that could be spamming. Could be a printer, or a laptop even, anything on the network is a suspect.

Also try this which seems to have helped:

- Removing fingerprint unlock. Perhaps I had 3 fingerprints, before I had 2, maybe that affected battery life and device being active.
- Removing one of the themes from the miui Themes app, it seems dodgy, using default theme seems to be helping too.

Network changes:

- Some routers and your phone's wifi chip might be a bit funny, so perhaps switch to Static fixed IP address for your phone instead of a dynamic DHCP ip address.
- Also try fixing the Wifi Router's Channel to a specific channel instead of leaving it on automatic. (Use WirelessNetView on PC to see which channels are quieter in your neighbourhood, choose between 1, 6 or 11 only)

Comment: Indeed, it could be interesting to monitor the network activity and check if there's something unusual. For instance, I'm surrounded with residential gateways with wifi, and had thought that at least one of them might cause the issue (for example because of repeated lookups). So we could determine if the battery drain is caused just by having the wifi module turned on, or when there is network activity in addition. But for my case, I have just turned the wifi off on the phone and called it a day.